# implicit type conversion for enum type in C

Tags: c, enums

In C, is there a way to declare an implicit type conversion for the following union type:

```
enum COMP { 
  LessThan, 
  Equal, 
  GreaterThan 
};
```

mapping it to, say, an integer:

```
enum COMP { 
  LessThan : 1, 
  Equal : 0, 
  GreaterThan : -1 
};
```

Comment: Implicit?  No, not in C.

Comment: sounds like an answer ! (is their a way to associate comparison operators to such type maybe ? so that LessThan < Equal < Greater than ?)

Comment: So by union you actually meant a mathematical union and not a C `union`?

Comment: yep. my bad. both `union` and `enum` in C are mathematical union, but `union` already means  something in C. I did not realize I was mixing terminology, which is confusing.

Comment: I removed the union tag (which is supposedly about SQL anyway).

Comment: Anyway, maybe consider not using an enum, since using -1, 0 and 1 integers as the result of functions is very common practice in C and shouldn't confuse anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is an `enum`, not a `union`.  And what it *seems* like you're asking is if you can assign specific values to enum constants.  You can do so like this:

```
enum COMP { 
  LessThan=-1, 
  Equal=0, 
  GreaterThan=1 
};
```

Also, enums are considered integer types, so you can safely convert to or from `int`.

Comment: yes. important point of terminology you make. both look like the general idea of "union types" but `enums` or `unions` in C already has a precise meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completion, if the values are to be in 1 intervals you can define only the first value:

```
enum COMP
{
    LessThan = -1,
    Equal, // will be 0
    GreaterThan // will be 1
};
```

Comment: Or `enum COMP { Equal, GreaterThan, LessThan = -GreaterThan };`.

Comment: very nice comment, should be an answer on its own!

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL, yes, it surely should, anyway, you can upvote elsewhere, Eric's good answers are plentiful...